# Concurrent File access in D

Tags: multithreading, logging, synchronization, d

I'm trying to implement a simple global logger in D that takes messages and writes them out to some `File`. I would like to make it accessible to all threads since I plan on initially having a single, simple log, so I made the class `synchronized`.

```
import std.stdio;
import std.exception;
import std.conv;

@trusted:

enum LogLevel {
    NONE,
    ERROR,
    WARN,
    INFO,
    DEBUG,
}

synchronized class Logger {

    LogLevel level = LogLevel.WARN;

    // The File* must be shared since this is a synchronized class
    @property shared(File*) output() { return to; }

    @property void output(shared(File*) f)
    {
        enforce(f != null);
        to = f;
    }

    void log(LogLevel l)(string message, string file = __FILE__, int line = __LINE__)
    {
        if(l < level)
            return;

        to.writeln(l.to!string, ": ", message, "(", file, ":", line.to!string, ")");
    }

    alias log!(LogLevel.ERROR) logError;
    alias log!(LogLevel.WARN) logWarn;
    alias log!(LogLevel.INFO) logInfo;
    alias log!(LogLevel.DEBUG) logDebug;

private:
    File* to = &stdout;
}
```

However, it appears `File.writeln` isn't very agreeable to being synchronized. I'm greeted with the following error from DMD:

> log.d(32): Error: template std.stdio.File.writeln does not match any function template declaration. Candidates are:
>   /usr/include/dlang/dmd/std/stdio.d(781):        std.stdio.File.writeln(S...)(S args)

What is the correct way to provide shared access to a file across multiple threads? Some initial thoughts:

1. In Alexandrescu's *The D Programming Language*, he mentions that `writeln` on `stout` is atomic with regards to the output stream, but I can't seem to find that anywhere in the online docs.
2. Even if point 1 is true, wouldn't I still want the `Logger` class to be syncrhonized for the sake of the output property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

easier is to spawn another thread and pass messages to it when you want to log

```
void log(LogLevel l)(string message, string file = __FILE__, int line = __LINE__){
    locate("logger").send(l,message,file,line);
}
```

then the thread will be:

```
void loggerLoop(){
    //setup file and such
    register(thisTid, "logger");
    scope(exit)unregister("logger");
    while(true){
        receive( (LogLevel l,string message, string file, int line){
            if(l < level)
                return;
            to.writeln(l.to!string, ": ", message, "(", file, ":", line.to!string, ")");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but how would one pass which `File*` (i.e. `to` in your example) to log in? Given that my options are to make the file thread-local or immutable (which would forbid writing to it), is it impossible to share a file among threads? What if I want to use stdout as my file? I certainly want to be able to print from both the logger and other sources.

Comment: @DejanLekic That's besides the point. Again, what if I want to use stdout as my file? I certainly want to be able to print to it from the rest of my program and not just the logger, which implies that I would want some way for multiple threads to share a single `File` handle.

Comment: If you take a look at the stdio.d code, you will realise that stdin, stdout and stderr are __gshared objects. These object are File objects, but tricky thing about them is that they are initialized at runtime by a static constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Having come from the C++/C#/Java world, it's taking a bit to reconfigure my brain to the message passing paradigm.